# WiX 3.6 - A complete WiX 3.6 multiinstance installer?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

Is there a complete WiX 3.6 multiinstance installer somewhere?

I just do not understand WiX 3.6, I guess. I have been reading for three days to try and construct a working example of a WiX 3.6 that will allow to install multiple instances of an application on the single machine.

Is there a functional example of how to do this with WiX 3.6?

Comment: Have you found an example? I'm also looking for this... thanks

Answer (score 4):

Here's some info I wrote a few years ago... since then, [WiX: A Developers Guide to Windows Installer XML](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849513724) has been released and is also a good resource for beginners. I didn't find it that great myself though. I still suggest reading [The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592972) as a starting point. Windows Installer and WiX isn't something you just pick up in a few days, it'll take a few months.

---

Go pick up a copy of [The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590592972). I've lost count of how many times I've recommended it to people who are getting stuck on the concepts and are struggling to understand how Windows Installer works. Make sure you grab the [Windows Installer SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=6A35AC14-2626-4846-BB51-DDCE49D6FFB6&displaylang=en) as well.

Getting to grasp with Windows Installer is the first stage of your learning, once that's sunk in you'll understand how [InstallShield](http://www.installshield.com/) works (or doesn't work as the case may be..). Wise, InstallShield, etc try to shield you from the underlying concepts and have their own trickery/hacks to get around the limitations of Windows Installer.

Stage two (if you're serious about understanding Windows Installer) is learning [WiX](http://wix.sf.net/) (The [WiX Tutorial](http://www.tramontana.co.hu/wix/) isn't too bad, although it's a bit out of date and targeted at WiX 2.0 rather than 3.x) and joining the [wix-users mailing list](http://n2.nabble.com/wix-users-f687560.html). Don't join the users list until you've finished the book mentioned above, you'll be well in over your head. Questions from those who don't understand the Windows Installer concepts largely go ignored, however questions from people who have done their homework will find it a great resource.

What's not covered in the book is Vista, Robert Flamings blog entries on [Understanding UAC and Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/rflaming/archive/tags/UAC+in+MSI/default.aspx) (written when Vista was in it's beta stage) are the best information you'll find on the topic.

One thing that both the Windows Installer and WiX teams is really good at is keeping the documentation (Help files) up to date. Whenever I'm working on setups I'll generally have **Wix.chm** and **Msi45.chm** open on one monitor ;)

Along with the documentation, blogs from people on the WiX and Windows Installer teams are great for learning new tricks, etc. Far too many to list here, but once you know the terminology you'll find most of them popping up in google results.

Also maybe go take a look at Rob Mensching's old blog [when setup isn't just xcopy](http://blogs.msdn.com/robmen/). Articles there are probably what convinced me that diving in and learning the underlying Windows Installer concepts would pay off in the long run. And it has :)

Comment: Great overview! +1 and added to favorites! ;)

Answer (score 3):

I've published a [blog post on this topic](http://ysdevlog.blogspot.com/2011/08/revisited-multiple-instance.html) some time ago. You can use the sample from there as a starting point. Take some time to play with it to understand it deep enough. Note that it's not only about WiX, but about Windows Installer as the underlying technology.

Comment: Should we know maximum count of instances during creating of msi package? What to do if I do not know how much the same instances will be installed?

Comment: Yes, we should. I would choose the reasonably big number which can be considered unlimited "virtually". I mean do you expect someone to install you software 20 times on a single target? I doubt so. Perhaps, 20 is a good number in this case. The less the better, of course - it will speed up the build and reduce the final size of the package.